# Rails error: "comparison of User with User failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm getting the following error in my rails app:

`comparison of User with User failed`

The relevant section of my controller looks like this:

```
class AssessmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :xml, :js, :pdf

def index
  @user = current_user
  @account = Account.find(@user.account_id)
  @assessments = Assessment.all
  respond_with @assessments
end
```

The relevant section of my view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |a| %>

<%= a.fields_for :users, @account.users.build do |u| %>

....
<%= a.submit "Sign-up", :class => "button", :disable_with => "Saving..." %>

<% end %>

<h1>Current users</h1>

<% for @user in @account.users.sort! { |b,a| a.id <=> b.id } %>
<%= render :partial => 'user' %>
<% end %>
```

The error seems to be originating around the `for @user in @account.users.sort!` section according to the error model, but removing it seems to be the addition of the `@account.users.build` in the fields_for section that creates it (but I need this as I want the user to be able to create a new user for that account. Can someone enlighten me to what is generating this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is indeed occurring on that line, because ActiveRecord models don't implement comparables by default. So when you say `@account.users.sort!`, the sort bombs out since it has no way to compare users with users.

There's two things you can do here:

1. Implement the comparison operator for your user model. Check out [this link](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/) for a blog post on how to do it, but it'd be something like:

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     def <=>(other)
       self.name <=> other.name
     end

   end
   ```
2. Tell the sort directly what comparison to use, like this:

   ```
   @account.users.sort! {|a, b| a.name <=> b.name}
   ```

Comment: I haven't heard the phrase "bombs out" in a while, but I still love it.

Comment: It looks like he's just sorting by descending id so `@account.users.order('id DESC')` is probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @veraticus - thanks man. Great Stackoverflow answer -> correct, concise and clear.